# Moving a list half its size against other list to get the common elements

Tags: python, pandas

I have two lists  `s1` and `s2`.  I need to slide the second list half its size on left and return the matching elements in first list. Then I need to move the second list one position and get the common elements as shown in the `Answer` below. I am plaaning to perforn some operation on each pair of sublists returned. What is the good way to accomplish this.

```
s1 = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
s2 = [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 25] 


11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 
21 22 23 24 25 25
```

Answer:

```
11 12 13 
24 25 25 

11 12 13 14 
23 24 25 25 

11 12 13 14 15 
22 23 24 25 25 

11 12 13 14 15 16 
21 22 23 24 25 25 

12 13 14 15 16 17 
21 22 23 24 25 25 

13 14 15 16 17 18 
21 22 23 24 25 25 


14 15 16 17 18 
21 22 23 24 25 


15 16 17 18 
21 22 23 24 


16 17 18 
21 22 23
```

Comment: Is this tagged 'pandas' because you'd like the solution to make use of that library?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is this used for (what kind of problems can it solve)?

Comment: I tagged pandas because I thought there may be something in there for treatment of this type of problem

Comment: This problem is from Signal processing domain and I want to perform some kind of operation on the sublests

Comment: Are you doing a 1-d convolution? Because there are fast library functions for that. In other words, that exactly the "some kind of operation" part is can be informative.

Comment: @jme, I am finding correlation using `xcorr` function but for some of the cases it is not giving me the desired result. Therefore, I wanted to implement my own function using `pearsonr` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you get the idea

```
s1 = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
s2 = [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 25] 

l1 = len(s1)
l2 = len(s2)
l = min(l1,l2)+1

k = l2/2;

for i in range(k,l2+1):
    print s1[:i]
    print s2[-i:]
    print

for i in range(1,l1-l2):
    print s1[i:i+l2]
    print s2[:]
    print


for i in reversed(range(k,l)):
    print s1[-i:]
    print s2[:i]
    print
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't do any bounds-checking, but this should do the trick:

```
def slide(s1, s2, size):
    start = size - len(s1)
    finish = len(s2) - size + 1
    for offset in xrange(start, finish):
        m = max(-offset, 0)
        n = max( offset, 0)
        l = min(len(s1) - m, len(s2) - n)

        yield s1[m:m+l], s2[n:n+l]
```

Or, if you'd prefer some `zip` trickery:

```
def slide(s1, s2, size):
    start = size - len(s1)
    finish = len(s2) - size + 1
    for offset in xrange(start, finish):
        m = max(-offset, 0)
        n = max( offset, 0)
        yield zip(*zip(s1[m:], s2[n:]))
```

Here's a test:

```
>>> s1 = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
>>> s2 = [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 25]
>>> list(slide(s1, s2, 3))
[([16, 17, 18], [21, 22, 23]),
 ([15, 16, 17, 18], [21, 22, 23, 24]),
 ([14, 15, 16, 17, 18], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]),
 ([13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 25]),
 ([12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 25]),
 ([11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 25]),
 ([11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [22, 23, 24, 25, 25]),
 ([11, 12, 13, 14], [23, 24, 25, 25]),
 ([11, 12, 13], [24, 25, 25])]
```

Note that this produces the pairs in reverse order.